# Boxplot sublists of a list

Tags: r, boxplot, sublist

i'm new to R.
I'm trying to boxplot the data (df, list) in each sub-list using `lapply`.
I have written this function:

```
group.box <- function(x) {
   lapply(X = x, FUN = boxplot)
}
```

Running it on the list that contains 6 sub-lists gives me 6 individual boxplot graph (6 separated graphs) and this text:

```
$sublist1
NULL

$sublist2
NULL

$sublist3
NULL

...
```

I tried to combine these graphs into one picture with 6 graphs:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
group.box(data)
dev.off()
```

But then I only get the text (as displayed above) with no graphs.
I thought maybe I should just export these 6 graphs into one pdf file.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to R :-). Could you please provide some more information about the data you want to plot, so that you have [created a fully reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it easier to help. Depending on the amount of data use `dput(yourdata)` or `dput(head(yourdata))`.

Comment: Thank you for your reference and suggestion, after running `dput(data)` and `dput(head(data))` which contained a large amount of data in various types that I don't think would be helpful. I usually try to bring maximum information. thank you again! :)

Comment: Ok, I see. Since the types included in the data are relevant for many tasks and functions you might also try `str(yourdata)`, which gives information about the structure of your object. Might still be too much information, but you can give it a try, simply wanted to add this for the purpose of learning.

Comment: OK, it is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
data <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100), c = rnorm(100), d = rnorm(100), e = rnorm(100), f = rnorm(100))

group.box <- function(x, plot_row, plot_col) {
    quartz()
    par(mfrow=c(plot_row,plot_col))
    lapply(X = x, FUN = boxplot)
}

group.box(data, 2,3)
```

You can of course use `png(...)` or `pdf(...)` etc. instead of `quartz()`

Comment: Thank you so much! I just want to add, that after the `lapply` function within the `group.box` function, a `dev.off()` command is necessary.

Comment: Only if you write to a file (png/pdf...), if you open a quartz window you probably want it to remain open. If you found my answer helpful you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)